# image inserted but not saved on server

Tags: php

Pls advise.
used code as follows:

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($conne, $_POST['title']);
    $ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($conne, $_POST['content']);
    $filename = $_FILES{"uploadfile"}["name"];
    $tempname = $_FILES{"uploadfile"}["temp_name"];
    $folder = "student/".$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($tempname,$folder);

    if($fn!="" && $ln!="" && $folder!="")



$query =  "INSERT INTO `content`(`title`, `content`, `user_id`,`picsource` ) VALUES ('$fn','$ln','$userprofile','$folder')";
$data = mysqli_query($conne, $query);
if($data)
{
    echo "Data inserted";
}


{
    echo "Allfeilds are required";
}
}


?>
<img src="<?php echo $result['picsource']; ?>" height='200' width= '200' align='left' vspace='10' hspace='10'   alt="">
```

All files including image files loading to server and texts are being displyed but image file not displaying.The image file also uploaded but not saving on server side folder. On checking the folder on server it shwos empty while in database it shows inserted.

Comment: You need to be definitely sure in your `$folder`. Also, search how to handle upload errors.[For example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#64418)

Comment: `$_FILES{"uploadfile"}` - where did you learn to use `{}` in that? that should be `$_FILES["uploadfile"]`

Comment: That SQL is potentially vulnerable to sql injection and where is `$userprofile` defined?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in a safer manner you ought to use a `prepared statement` - also the `$_FILES` variable uses square brackets rather than curly...

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_FILES['uploadfile'], $userprofile ) ){
        $title=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $content=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'content', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );;

        $obj=(object)$_FILES['uploadfile'];
        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $imgpath=sprintf( '%s/student/%s', __DIR__, $name );

        $sql='insert into `content` ( `title`, `content`, `user_id`,`picsource` ) values ( ?, ?, ?, ? )';
        $stmt=$conne->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param( 'ssss', $title, $content, $userprofile, $imgpath );
            if( move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $imgpath ) ){
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I am not a professional learning by hit & trial method. If you pls whatsup me ur mail id shall send you the file. The $userprofile is defined in session_start to get user_id. However i am trying your codes but not able to insert the data on my local host. pls...my whats No: is  +9779851128130      regds Rabindra, Nepal

Comment: Sir Your suggested code is working data inserted. While displaying the data all data are being displayed except image.

Comment: please show what your code is that tries to display image and inspect the image in the console to see what the path is

Comment: Using your codes data inserted even displayed but image is not displaying. Pls help. I am a learner.

Comment: I can't help if you do not show me the code you use to display the image or what the html source code shows for image path

Comment: <?php
      error_reporting(0);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id`  DESC"  ;
      $data = mysqli_query($conne, $query);
      $total = mysqli_num_rows($data);
      echo $total;
      if($total!= 0);
      if ($conne)
     {
        ?>
        <?php
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
        {
            echo "<tr>                    <th>".$result['content']."</th>
                    <th><a href='$result[picsource]'><img src='".$result['picsource']."'height='100px' width='100px'</></a></th>

Comment: Not really what I meant... but OK, what is the content of `$result['picsource']`???

Comment: <?php
   error_reporting(0);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `content` ORDER BY `id`  DESC"  ;
 $data = mysqli_query($conne, $query);
  $total = mysqli_num_rows($data);
  echo $total;
  if($total!= 0);
  if ($conne)
   { while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data))
 { echo "<tr>
 <th>".$result['user_id']."</th>
 <th>".$result['title']."</th>
<th>".$result['content']."</th>
 <th><a href='$result[picsource]'><img src='".$result['picsource']."'height='100px' width='100px'</></a></th>
</tr>";
    }
    }
   else
   {
    echo "Connection Failed because No records found";
    }
   ?>

Comment: please give me your mail id to mail you the codes. Mine is rabindrakgupta@gmail.com

Comment: no - no emails... look at the rendered HTML source in the browser ( ie: right click, view source ) - find the image, copy whatever it says for the `src` attribute and paste here as a comment.

Comment: c:\xampp\htdocs\aspif\chaupal/student/IMG_20181114_061057.jpg

Comment: OK - the image will not display because you are using the FULL local path which is a FILESYSTEM path. The correct path should be, I think, `/aspif/chaupal/student/IMG_20181114_061057.jpg` ~ remember that urls use a forward slash!

Comment: Basically you will need to either modify the path that is stored in the db before you save it or before you display it!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code:

```php
 $filename = $_FILES{"uploadfile"}["name"];
 $tempname = $_FILES{"uploadfile"}["temp_name"];
```

with the following code:

```php
 $filename = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
 $tempname = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["temp_name"];
```

Comment: Sir ,  Lot of thanks. Now the problem of display is also solved with your given codes. Only replaced the slash by backslash   .%\student\%s    Again thanks for the help SIr.

Comment: All good. Consider marking it as correct and upvote it. if I solved the error.